# Como adicionar o valor do atributo id e do text de um select a partir do evento click de um botão?

Tags: jquery, html

Preciso adicionar no objeto `Select` o `Id` e o `Texto` a partir dessa função:

```
//Adiciono o item retirado da table html para o objeto html Select
            $.each(_arrDescricao, function (text, key) {
                var option = new Option(key, text);
                $('.selListaItem').append($(option));
            });
```

o problema é que só consigo adicionar o `text`, como faço para adicionar o `Id` no `Select`? 
Esse é o código completo:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnRemoverItem", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var _arrId = new Array();
        var _arrDescricao = new Array();

        $("#tableHtml tbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                var _id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-id]').data('id');
                var _descricao = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-descricao]').data('descricao');
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();

                _arrId.push(_id);
                _arrDescricao.push(_descricao);
            };

        });

        //Adiciono o item retirado da table html para o objeto html Select
        $.each(_arrDescricao, function (text, key) {
            var option = new Option(key, text);
            $('.selListaItem').append($(option));
        });       

    });
```

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi sua dúvida, você quer montar uma lista de options de um select com um certo ID e certo TEXTO (value)?

Comment: Isso mesmo ! Eu já tenho o **id** = `_id` e o **texto** = `_descricao`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode alterar um pouco a estrutura que armazena os `ids` e `textos` e adicionar dessa forma:

```
$("#tableHtml tbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        var _id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-id]').data('id');
        var _descricao = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-descricao]').data('descricao');
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        _arr.push({
            id: _id,
            descricao: _descricao
        });
    };

});

//Adiciono o item retirado da table html para o objeto html Select
_arr.forEach(function(item) {
    $('.selListaItem').append("<option id=" + item.id + "value='foo'>" + item.descricao + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: Obrigado!, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode armazenar o id e descricao em um mesmo array e usa-lo depois. Seguindo sua mesma estrutura, vou chama-lo de `_arrData`.

```
_arrData.push({id: _id, descricao: _descricao});
```

Dessa forma, o `key` passa a ser um objeto e não só o texto. Assim você constrói o `Option` já passando o `id` como **value** e `descricao` como **texto**:

```
$.each(_arrData, function (text, key) {
  var option = new Option(key.descricao, key.id);
  $('.selListaItem').append($(option));
});
```

**Código completo** ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/iazzetta/pen/eGbbvE)):

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnRemoverItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var _arrData = new Array();

  $("#tableHtml tbody").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

      var _id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-id]').data('id');
      var _descricao = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-descricao]').data('descricao');
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();

      _arrData.push({id: _id, descricao: _descricao});
    };

  });

  //Adiciono o item retirado da table html para o objeto html Select
  $.each(_arrData, function (text, key) {
    var option = new Option(key.descricao, key.id);
    $('.selListaItem').append($(option));
  });       

});
```

Comment: Obrigado! @Guilherme IA!